# Searching and counting a word in a text file, but unable to ignore full stop using delimiters

Tags: javascript, java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Searching and counting a word in a text file, but unable to ignore full stop using delimiters. I am using a delimiter to ignore the full stop if present after a word. I am trying to create a file by using users input and then ask them for a word that they want to search in the text file and show them the number of times it has occurred in the text.
    this is my main class
    public class Main 
    {

```
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
{

       str s=new str();
        s.writer();
        s.reader();


}
}



this is my class that has both the methods to create and read a file.

public void reader()
{
      String s;
    int i=0;
    //Reading The File
        try {
            FileReader f=new FileReader("karan.txt");
              Scanner sc=new Scanner(f);
               Scanner st=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter string to be found and counted: ");
                s=st.nextLine();
                System.out.print("\n");
                sc.useDelimiter(".");
                sc.nextLine();
              while(sc.hasNext())
              {
                  if(sc.next().equals(s))
              {

                  i++;
              }
              }
             System.out.println("The number of times the word "+s+" is present is "+i);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
}
 //Writing The File
public void writer() throws IOException
{

        try {
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("karan.txt");
              PrintWriter p=new PrintWriter(fw) ;
               Scanner st=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter Text.");
                p.print(st.nextLine());
                p.close();
            System.out.println("File has been written successfuly.");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
}
```

this is the output when I have kept the delimiter line

```
    Enter Text.
    karan is best of the best.
    File has been written successfuly.
    Enter string to be found and counted: best
    The number of times the word best is present is 0
```

this is the output when I remove the delimiter line
Enter Text.

```
    karan is best of the best
    File has been written successfuly.
    Enter string to be found and counted: best
    The number of times the word best is present is 2
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 23 seconds)
```

but I want the answer to be 2 even when I write 
        karan is best of the best.
notice the full stop at the end, i want the compiler to ignore the full stop and give me the answer 2 i.e. it should also count the word best with full stop at the end.

thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: What has this to do with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a couple of changes into `reader()` method:

- Remove `sc.nextLine();` before `while` loop, that skips the first line and advances the cursor to next line, it won't work if file has only one line.
- Change `sc.useDelimiter(".");` to `sc.useDelimiter("\\.");`, You need to escape `.` character as `useDelimiter` accepts regex and `.` means any character in regex.
- Change `if(sc.next().equals(s))` to `if(sc.next().contains(s))`, you just need to check if the `string` is present anywhere in the line.

Below should work:

```
try {
    FileReader f = new FileReader("G://1.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter string to be found and counted: ");
    s = st.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n");
    sc.useDelimiter("\\.");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (sc.next().contains(s)) {

            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of times the word " + s + " is present is " + i);

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

Comment: didn't work when i wrote "karan best and best." and searched for word best it only gave me count 1 not 2, which it is suppose to give. Compiler is ignoring the full stop after the second "best".